# Create a list of negative & positive values from a table of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
    A            B       C        D        E           F                 G    
1                 Q1     Q2       Q3      Q4      Negative values  Positive values
2   Asset 1      -50     85      -90      70         -10                 5 
3   Asset 2      -28    -80      -45      60         -15                27         
4   Asset 3      -30     50       55     -10         -20                50      
5   Asset 4      -20      5      -80     -15          :                 :  
6   Asset 5       35    -30       27     -98          :                 :
7                                                     :                 :
```

In `Cells A1:E6` I have different assets with their performance from quarter `Q1-Q4`.

In `Column F` I want to have a list of all negative performances of the assets starting with the greates negative one (in this case `-10`).

In `Column G` I want to have a list of all positive performances of the assets starting with the lowest postive one (in this case `5`).

Do you have any idea of a formula that could create these lists?

**Note:** All values are unique!

Comment: Is it ever possible that the lowest positive won't be in the same row as the lowest negative?

Comment: @Scott Craner: I edited the description in my question.

Comment: @Matt Cremeens: No, that is not sure. The numbers are not structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LARGE and SMALL as Array formulas

negative:

```
=LARGE(IF($C$2:$F$6<0,C$2:$F$6),ROW(1:1))
```

and

Positive:

```
 =SMALL(IF($C$2:$F$6>0,C$2:$F$6),ROW(1:1))
```

Both are array formulas and need to confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. As far as I see the formula also works if the values are not unique.

Comment: Yes it should, it will list each.