# Create a list of values from a table of values and exclude certain values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
    A            B       C        D        E              F                 G    
1                 Q1     Q2       Q3      Q4        Positive values
2   Asset 1      -50     85      -90      70             85 
3   Asset 2      -28    -80      -45      60             70         
4   Asset 3      -30     50       55     -10             60      
5   Asset 4      -20      5      -80     -15              :  
6   Asset 5       35    -30       27     -98              :
7
```

In Cells `A1:E6` I have different assets with their performance from quarter `Q1-Q4`.

In `Column F` I create a list of all postive performances of the assets using the formula from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540422/create-a-list-of-negative-positive-values-from-a-table-of-values):

```
Column F = {LARGE(IF($B$2:$E$6>0,B$2:$E$6),ROW(B1:E1))}
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, now I want to exclude certain values from the list in `Column F`. For example I do not want that number `85` or number `70` appear in the list. Therefore, I tried to modify the formula to:

```
Column F = {LARGE(IF(AND($B$2:$E$6>0,$B$2:$E$6<>85,$B$2:$E$6<>70),B$2:$E$6),ROW(B1:E1))}
```

However, now I get `0` as result.

Do you have any idea of a formula that could solve this issue?

Comment: You could use [AutoFilter](https://support.office.com/article/quick-start-filter-data-by-using-an-autofilter-08647e19-11d1-42f6-b376-27b932e186e0) to exclude certain values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path. Instead of using `AND`, a nested `IF` would work.
You need to create a new `IF` criteria for every new condition you want to test.
So if you want to exclude 85 and 70 you need to add two additional IF statements.

Formula for Column F would be:

```
={LARGE(IF($B$2:$E$6>0,IF($B$2:$E$6<>85,IF($B$2:$E$6<>70,B$2:$E$6))),ROW(B1:E1))}
```

You can read here how the formula process is: [Minimum if multiple criteria](https://exceljet.net/formula/minimum-if-multiple-criteria)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

- Create an array of 0's where 0 is equivalent to a negative number or the excluded values

---

```
($B$2:$E$6>0)*($B$2:$E$6<>85)*($B$2:$E$6<>70)
```

- 1/(…  will convert that to 1's and errors
- Multiply by the original to create an array of original values and errors

---

```
 =1/(($B$2:$E$6>0)*($B$2:$E$6<>85)*($B$2:$E$6<>70)) * B2:E6
```

- Use the aggregate function to get the results you want

---

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(($B$2:$E$6>0)*($B$2:$E$6<>85)*($B$2:$E$6<>70))*$B$2:$E$6,ROWS($1:1))
```

Fill down to get the 2nd, 3rd, etc largest

Answer (score 1):

If you have data in column **F** and you want to extract all values that are not **70** or **85** into column **G**, then in **G2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(F$2:F$9999, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$999)/((F$2:F$9999<>85)*(F$2:F$9999<>70)), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Note that this approach does not require the use of an array formula.